# VS22 Database project object with same name in different databases

Tags: database, visual-studio, dacpac

I have a database project in VS2022 that contains several databases, each as their own project.

I repeatedly have problems with objects in different databases, that have the same name. E.g. in Db1 there is a user called "job". Db2 also has a user called "job" and uses data from Db1. Now, when I try to build Db2 I get an error `model already has an element that has the same name`.

This happens with users, tables, procedures, ... but somewhat randomly. Some tables in different databases have the same name and while building no error occurs. Then sometimes if I change anything in the Database model suddenly such errors happen although it worked for months before. I recently changed the collation of a database and suddenly I get dozens of this "already has an object" although the same databases worked before. Sometimes it can be fixed by closing VS22, removing the `.dbmdl` files and reopen the project, sometimes not.

I could change all objects to include their unique database name, but this would be a lot of work and not reasonable since tables with the same name in different databases shouldn't be a problem. Does anyone know why those errors occure randomly and how could one avoid that?

Comment: Show a pair of sqlproj files which produce conflicts with dacpac/project reference definitions.